# Adding line numbers to an overflowing TextField

Tags: flutter, textfield

I'm looking for a way to display line numbers alongside a (multiline) textfield. (In a way which is similar to most IDE's.)

I started out with something similar to this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final textInputController = TextEditingController();
  final scrollController = ScrollController();
  ValueNotifier<FocusNode> textCursorLocation = ValueNotifier<FocusNode>(FocusNode());
  int linesCount = 1;
  String textInput = 'Hello World';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 30,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    for(var i = 0; i < linesCount; i++) Text((i+1).toString(),),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TextField(
                enableIMEPersonalizedLearning: false,
                enableSuggestions: false,
                focusNode: textCursorLocation.value,
                onChanged: (text){
                  textInput = text;

                  linesCount= '\n'.allMatches(text).length + 1;
                  setState(() {});
                },
                controller: textInputController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                maxLines: 50,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

This works fine for me until a line starts overflowing, then the line numbers obviously don't line up to the text line anymore.

I think there might be a solution to this problem by using LineMetrics to detect overflowing text.

```
List<ui.LineMetrics> lines = textPainter.computeLineMetrics();
print(lines[0].hardBreak.toString());
```

This is only possible within a CustomPaint widget. Is it possible to do something similar with a TextField? Or should I look for an alternative way?

Comment: Where do you want to use linesCount exactly?

Comment: I use the linesCount integer to keep track of the amount of lines present in the TextField.